# i have a float number i want it be converted as time in python

Tags: python-3.x

my number is 0.528084743 and the time for it is 12:40:27.what is the python code to match that float to time? can any one help me?
thanks in advance...
and i tried the below code

```html
from datetime import datetime
excel_date = 42139
dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + excel_date - 2)
tt = dt.timetuple()
print dt
print tt
```

but it is not helping me

Comment: Could you explain why 0.528084743 should be exactly 12:40:27?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this float is fraction of a day.

```
from datetime import timedelta

float_time = 0.528084743
seconds_per_day = 24* 60 *60
time_in_seconds = round(float_time * seconds_per_day)

time = timedelta(seconds=time_in_seconds)
print(time)
```

Output (Python 3.6.1):

> 12:40:27

Comment: If the answer is helpful, you can consider accepting it.